# Cannot get css menu to use dropdown submenus or be responsive

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, responsive

I have a beautiful css menu that I would love to continue to use but have spent the last week trying to make it so I can have drop down sub-menus, unlimited depth (and have them all stay within screen of course).  I have also been trying to make it responsive with media queries but have failed on that part as well.  It shouldn't be that hard to figure out but I cannot seem to figure it out.  Is there anyone that can help me along to get this menu responsive and dropdown?

HTML

```
<header id="header" class="page-header js-header" data-selenium="page-header">
  <div class="main-nav">
<div class="nav" id="main_menu">
  <ul class="topnav">
    <li><a href="/c/browse/Photography/ci/989/N/4294538916" target="_self"><span>Photography</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="/c/browse/Computers-Solutions/ci/9581/N/4294542559 " target="_self"><span>Computers</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="/c/browse/Professional-Video/ci/3755/N/4294545851" target="_self"><span>Pro Video</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="/c/browse/Lighting-Studio/ci/1161/N/4294551176" target="_self"><span>Lighting <span class="lighting">&amp; Studio</span></span></a>
      <ul class="hidden">
        <li><a href="#">Drop Down Test</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Drop Down Test</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Drop Down Test</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/c/browse/Professional-Audio/ci/12154/N/4294550705" target="_self"><span>Pro Audio</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="/c/browse/Mobile/ci/8565/N/4294542748" target="_self"><span>Mobile</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="/c/browse/Home-Entertainment/ci/4600/N/4294544179" target="_self"><span>TVs &amp; Entertainment</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="/c/browse/Camcorders/ci/1820/N/4294548420" target="_self"><span>Camcorders</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="/c/browse/Surveillance-Video/ci/3496/N/4293342959" target="_self"><span>Surveillance</span></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Drop Down Test</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Drop Down Test</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Drop Down Test</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/c/browse/Binoculars-Scopes/ci/978/N/4294541872" target="_self"><span>Optics</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="/c/browse/A-V-Presentation/ci/3644/N/4294546288" target="_self"><span>A/V Presentation</span></a></li>
    <li class="border-link"><a href="/c/category/2870/Used_Equipment.html">Used</a></li>
    <li class="border-link"><a href="/explora">Boogers</a></li>
    <li class="icon">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">☰</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

</div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300italic,300,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic);

a, abbr, acronym, address, applet, article, aside, audio, b, big, blockquote, body, button, canvas, caption, center, cite, code, dd, del, details, dfn, div, dl, dt, em, embed, fieldset, figcaption, figure, footer, form, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, header, hgroup, html, i, iframe, img, ins, kbd, label, legend, li, mark, menu, nav, object, ol, output, p, pre, q, ruby, s, samp, section, small, span, strike, strong, sub, summary, sup, table, tbody, td, tfoot, th, thead, time, tr, tt, u, ul, var, video {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    font:inherit;
    vertical-align:baseline
}
b, strong {
    font-weight:700
}
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display:block
}
body {
    line-height:1
}
ol, ul {
    list-style:none
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes:none
}
.new-page-width, .page-width {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto
}
body {
    font-family:OpenSans, Arial, sans-serif
}
.c1 {
    color:#000
}
.c2 {
    color:#595959
}
.c3 {
    color:#ccc
}
.c4 {
    color:#666
}
.c5 {
    color:#165485
}
.c6 {
    color:#B80505
}
.c7 {
    color:#900
}
.c8 {
    color:#105f9f
}
.c9 {
    color:#696969
}
.c10 {
    color:#81b1d7
}
.c11 {
    color:#2e2e2e
}
.c12 {
    color:#e7e7e7
}
.c13 {
    color:#474747
}
.c14 {
    color:#565656
}
.c15 {
    color:#1B4D88
}
.c16 {
    color:#f93
}
.c17 {
    color:#fdf4b0
}
.c18 {
    color:#fff
}
.c31 {
    color:#1A5888
}
.c34 {
    color:#12a16c
}
.c35 {
    color:#b2b2b2
}
.c36 {
    color:#999
}
.c37 {
    color:#7f7f7f
}
.c38 {
    color:#345
}
.c39 {
    color:#333
}
.c40 {
    color:#708f3f
}
.c41 {
    color:#769e2d
}
.c42 {
    color:#f0f0f0
}
body .bold {
    font-weight:700
}
body .smbold {
    font-weight:600
}
.italic, em, i {
    font-style:italic
}
.upper {
    text-transform:uppercase
}
.lower {
    text-transform:lowercase
}
.capitalize {
    text-transform:capitalize
}
.underline {
    text-decoration:underline
}
.noUnderline, .underline-on-hover {
    text-decoration:none
}
.underline-on-hover:hover {
    text-decoration:underline
}
.cursor-pointer {
    cursor:pointer
}
*, :after, :before {
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box
}
.full-width {
    width:100%
}
.page-width {
    width:960px
}
.new-page-width {
    max-width:1350px;
    min-width:1004px;
    border-left:20px solid transparent;
    border-right:20px solid transparent
}
.left {
    float:left
}
.right {
    float:right
}
.clearfix:after {
    visibility:hidden;
    display:block;
    font-size:0;
    content:".";
    clear:both;
    height:0
}

.page-header {
    color:#707070;
    background:#ededed;
    font-size:16px;
    position:relative
}

.page-header a, .page-header a:hover {
    text-decoration:none
}
.header-main, .header-top>div, .main-nav .nav {
    max-width:1350px;
    min-width:1060px;
    margin:0 auto
}
.header-top {
    border-bottom:1px solid #c2c2c2;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    font-size:12px
}

.header-top a {
    padding:0 10px 0 0
}
#header .logo {
    top: 5px;
    margin-right:35px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0
}
#header .logo svg {
    width:87px!important;
    height:60px!important;
    pointer-events:all
}

.header-main {
    padding:0;
    height:80px;
    position:relative
}
.header-main>* {
    float:left
}
```

Here is the fiddle if you want to play with it: https://jsfiddle.net/zyh7grur/1/

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at your fiddle css stylesheet. You were missing a section for the 'hover' event on each li. I just added the following:

```
.main-nav li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  z-index: 9999;
  background: #769e2d;
}
```

And corrected this:

```
.main-nav li ul {
display: none;
position: absolute;
}
```

I see ti working now. But you can check the following jsfiddle, just in case: https://jsfiddle.net/zyh7grur/29/

Comment: I've worked on it a little more, been able to style it however I cannot seem to get the sub-menu to be vertical.  I've tried a few things but all that I got was only one sub-menu item showing.  Here is the updated fiddle with what I have done. https://jsfiddle.net/zyh7grur/30/